# How to serialize an object inside an object, inside an object

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

My models are as follows:

```
class Route(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    public = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class POI(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    cemiterio = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    cemiterioID = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    gisID = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    
class POIInRoute(models.Model):
    POIID = models.ForeignKey(POI,related_name='poi', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    routeID = models.ForeignKey(Route,related_name='pirs', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField(null= True, blank=True)
    order = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
```

I want to create a Route serializer that serializes a Route, its related POIInRoutes and the POI related to the POIInRoute.

I have already tried without success(serializers.py):

```
class poiSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = POI
        fields = ('id','description','cemiterio','cemiterioID','gisID')

class pirSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    poi = poiSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = POIInRoute
        fields = ('id', 'POIID', 'routeID', 'description', 'order','poi')

class RouteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pirs = pirSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Route
        fields = ('id','name','description','public', 'pirs')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Changing  Your **serializers.py** code to this :

```
class poiSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = POI
        fields = ('id','description','cemiterio','cemiterioID','gisID')

class pirSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    POIID =  poiSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = POIInRoute
        fields = ('id', 'POIID', 'routeID', 'description', 'order')

class RouteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pirs = pirSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Route
        fields = ('id','name','description','public', 'pirs')
```

**views.py** looks like this:

```
class RouteView(APIView):
    def get(self,request):
        route = Route.objects.all()  # this is can vary if you want to serializer a specific  queryset
        
        serializer = RouteSerializer(route , many=True,)
        
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

This worked for me.